# how to increment array count in bash?

Tags: bash, awk

The awk code below counts the frequency of the occurrence of $1.  I would like the bash equivalent for this code?

```
a[$1]++}END{for(x in a)print a[x],x
```

How would I do this with a bash array?

Comment: So you looked up bash arrays and then what happened?

Comment: That's not valid `awk` code, you have mismatching braces.

Comment: You don't need arrays, use the `uniq -c` command to count the frequency of words.

Comment: Hi @thatotherguy I became overwhelmed as I'm not familiar with bash.  I would never have figured out the solution as I didn't know I needed an associated array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there will be bash-oriented and smarter ways, the literal translation of your code will be:

```
declare -A a                    # you need to explicitly declare an associative array

while read -r x rest; do        # "x" is assigned to the first field ($1) and "rest" to the rest
    ((a[$x]++))                 # increment the count
done

for x in "${!a[@]}"; do         # iterate over the array
    echo "${a[$x]},$x"          # print the result
done
```

The code above waits for the input via the stdin and you need to feed the input with a redirect or a pipe.

Comment: Thank you so much @tshiono , I am able to get this to work.

Comment: @Brajesh good to know it works. If you feel my answer
solves well your problem, I'd appreciate if you can accept my answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. BR.

Comment: Done @tshiono - I'm glad you asked because I didn't know about the meaning of the check box.

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of occurrences of `elem` in `arr`:

```sh
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}" | grep -cw elem
```